# Android Detect when Activity finish in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My MainActivity launch a fragment, this fragment launch MySecondActivity and when the SecondActivity finish she launch the ThirdActivity.

I would like that my MainActivity detect when ThirdActivity finish.

I try to use onActivityResult, this is the code when I finish MySecondActivity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  setResult(Utils.RESULT_FROM_ORDER_FINISH, intent);
  OrderFinishActivity.this.finish();
  OrderFinishActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

In my MainActivity I got the onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Utils.RESULT_FROM_ORDER_FINISH) {
        // do thing
    }
}
```

the Fragment launch SecondActivity with

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(activity, activityClass);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

And the SecondActivity launch third one with the same code

But the onActivityResult is not trigger, I think the Fragment got the info and I would like that he transfer the info to the MainActivity

Comment: How are you launchig the second activity? Are you using startActivityForResult(...)?

Comment: from where you are launching the second activity .. is it from fragment.? Please share that code aswell

Comment: you haven't startActivityforResult(), then how did you Activity A calls your onActivityResult() method

Comment: I made an edit of my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For updates Question

What you can do is

```
1 > startActivityForResult(SecondActivity).
2 > Finish SecondActvity set result_ok.
3 > In OnActivityResult of FirstActivity startActivityForResult(ThirdActivity).
4 > Finish ThirdActvity set result_ok. 
5 > In OnActivityResult of FirstActivity  do your stuff.
```

Point here is do not launch ThirdActivity from SecondActivity but start it from the FirstActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace if you are launching `Second activity` from fragment

```
startActivityForResult(intent, Defines.FILTER_BY_CATALOGUE);
```

with

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,Utils.RESULT_FROM_ORDER_FINISH);
```

and replace

```
setResult(Utils.RESULT_FROM_ORDER_FINISH, intent);
// 1st parameter is not request code but result code
```

with

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

in `Second Activity`

Comment: thanks the onActivityResult is now trigger but, the requestCode have the good value but my resultCode is always 0,

Comment: Have you done the same as i mentioned setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

Comment: Yes I just made an edit, I have an other activity between the two other, maybe this block the resultCode

Comment: Don't just edit your question from the original problem and change the whole requirements just ask other question.

Comment: check my other answer

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke `startActivityForResult` from a fragment and you want to parent activity triggers `onActivityResult`, you should start new activity getting parent activity instance:

```
//This way will work
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,Utils.RESULT_FROM_ORDER_FINISH);

//This way will not
startActivityForResult(intent,Utils.RESULT_FROM_ORDER_FINISH);
```